# adding lazy constraints to Gurobi in Matlab

Tags: matlab, gurobi

I just wanted to add lazy constraints to Gurobi, I did not find the parameters about callback and lazy constraints. What is the way to add lazy constraints in Matlab?

Answer (score 2):

The [Gurobi Matlab interface](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.5/refman/matlab_api_overview.html) does not support callbacks or lazy constraints. You would need to use any of the other APIs (except for the R API) to use these features.

In both the R and Matlab interfaces, the model is fully constructed and then solved - there is no interaction with the code during the optimization process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try another API.